# Ejecutar una primera petición post y consecutivamente ejecutar la segunda petición post

Tags: angular, typescript

comunidad, como puedo hacer para una vez realizada una petición post y yo reciba la respuesta de un ID, se ejecute una segunda petición post?,
Actualmente, mando un JSON a una petición post y recibo un ID, y se ejecuta la segunda petición sin esperar la respuesta de la primera.

Me comentaron de las promesas, pero no tengo idea de como implementarlo, estoy en esta gran encrucijada, no se donde ni como meter las promesas en el código.

Adjunto el código, espero pueda ayudarme por favor:

```js
saveInstitucion(bandModifi: boolean) {
    this.submitted = true;    
 
            let jsonFInal = {
            id_estado: this.m_id_estado,
            id_municipio: this.m_id_municipio,

/* Guardado de la primera peticion */       this.apisInstitucionesService.createInstitucion(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFInal))).subscribe({
            next: (v) =>{
              if(v != null ){
                this.refreshTable();
                this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Completado', detail: 'Institución creado correctamente.', life: 3000});
                const id = v[0];
                //En esta guardo el ID de la peticion
                this.id_institucion = Number(id.success); 
              }else{
                this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error Institución no se pudo crear.', life: 3000});
              }
            },
            error: (e) =>{
              this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error al guarda la institución', life: 3000});
              console.error(e);
            }, 
            complete: () => {
              console.info('complete institucion') 
            }
          });

          /* Ejecuto la segunda peticion*/
          //Si id-institucion viene vacio muestro msj si no ejecuto 
          //la segunda peticion
          if(!this.id_institucion){
            console.log(No hay dato del ID);
          } else{
            if(this.informacion_Contacto.length){
              for (let contacto of this.informacion_Contacto) {

                let idinstitucion = contacto.id_institucion;
                //Comparo si viene en cero asigno el id del registro anterior
                contacto.id_institucion = idinstitucion == 0 ? this.id_institucion : 0;
//Guardo la informacion                this.apisAsesoresService.createAsesor(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contacto))).subscribe({
                  next: (v) =>{
                    if(v != null ){
                      //this.refreshTable();
                      this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Completado', detail: 'Asesor creado correctamente.', life: 3000});
                    }else{
                      this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error , asesor no se pudo crear.', life: 3000});
                    }
                  },
                  error: (e) =>{
                    this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error al guardar el asesor.', life: 3000});
                    console.error(e);
                  }, 
                  complete: () => console.info('complete asesor') 
                });
              }
            }
          }
```

**Actualización**
Si imprimo en consola **this.informacion_Contacto** me lo trae vacio, eso estando dentro del complete de la primera petición y si lo pongo dentro del next o fuera de la primera me trae la información mi variable. **A que se deberá q no me lo muestre dentro del complete de la primera petición??**

Comment: Hola amigo @Yussef ya lo intente poniéndolo en la parte del complet, pero no me detecta el id, y nunca se ejecuta el guardado de la segunda petición. Hasta ahorita es lo unico que me detiene, lo puse despues de que se guarda correctamente, en el complet pero no ejecuta.

Comment: probaste poniendo la segunda solicitud dentro de un setTimeout()? podes ponerle un retraso de 1 2 o 3 segundos a ese timeout dependiendo de cuanto tarde en llegar la primera respuesta, y que pasados esos segundos se ejecute la segunda solicitud cuando la primera en teoria ya deberia haber terminado. Pero bueno si la primera tarda mas o menos 2 seg en llegar, a la segunda la envolves en un timeout(retraso) de 3 segundos solo para asegurarte.

Comment: En que parte y como lo añado amigo? Asi settimeout y envuelvo toda la segunda api??

Comment: anda al chat de la publicacion pasada

Comment: Perdón por contestar tarde no tenía internet en mi pueblo, y metí la segunda petición en un settimeout, elimine los then y el fetch no se si fue buena idea) el detalle es que la variable donde almaceno la informacion para mandarla en la segunda peticion me regresa vacio, pero si lo saco del timesetout me trae la info normal :(